# How can I make dynamic date in Presto SQL

Tags: sql, function, dynamic, automation, presto

I wanted to make a metric data check table - below is what I have now. I wish to automate part of "2021-04-30", so every time I run the logic, it will dynamically change to the last day of every month. (iterate from 2021-01-31, 2021-02-28, 2021-03-31,.....)

```
CREATE TABLE data_check_result AS
WITH day_count AS (
    SELECT day(date '2021-04-30' - date '2020-01-01') AS ideal_days 
)
, metric AS (
    SELECT country
        , day(max(datepartition)- date '2020-01-01') AS actual_has_days
    FROM table
    GROUP BY 1
)
SELECT date '2021-04-30' AS report_period
    , country
    , 'metric_a' AS metric_name
    , CASE WHEN metric.actual_has_days = day_count.ideal_days THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS data_passed
FROM day_count
JOIN metric
    ON 1=1
;
```

Ideal output table

```
report_period    country             metric_name    data_passed
2021-04-30       Australia           metric_a            YES
2021-04-30       Canada              metric_a            NO
2021-04-30       China               metric_a            YES
2021-03-31       US                  metric_a            NO
2021-03-31       Canada              metric_a            YES
....
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`last_day_of_month`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html?highlight=last_day_of_month#last_day_of_month) function to obtain the last day of each month:

```sql
SELECT last_day_of_month(date('2021-' || cast(month as varchar) || '-01'))
FROM UNNEST(sequence(1,12)) t(month)
```

=>

```
   _col0
------------
 2021-01-31
 2021-02-28
 2021-03-31
 2021-04-30
 2021-05-31
 2021-06-30
 2021-07-31
 2021-08-31
 2021-09-30
 2021-10-31
 2021-11-30
 2021-12-31
(12 rows)
```

You can put it all together in this manner (not verified, but it should be a good start):

```sql
CREATE TABLE data_check_result AS
WITH metric AS (
    SELECT country
        , day(max(datepartition)- date '2020-01-01') AS actual_has_days
    FROM table
    GROUP BY 1
),
last_days_of_month AS (
    SELECT last_day_of_month(date('2021-' || cast(month as varchar) || '-01')) last_day
    FROM UNNEST(sequence(1,12)) t(month)
)
SELECT
    last_day AS report_period
    , country
    , 'metric_a' AS metric_name
    , CASE WHEN metric.actual_has_days = day_count.ideal_days THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS data_passed
FROM metric
   CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT last_day, day(last_day - date '2020-01-01') AS ideal_days
        FROM last_days_of_month
   )
```